# How can i print the value in Selenium, i am only getting <generator object <genexpr> at, and find_elements does not work

Tags: python, list, selenium, loops, selector

im am trying to get the values i added to a list with selenium and print them out. But i am only getting this: <generator object  at 0x000001B924EC7990>. How can i print the values in the list.

I also tried to shorten the xpath with "//tr[@class= 'text3'][11]/td" but it didnt work.

Like you can see i tried to loop through the list and convert it in text, but it also didnt work.

Would this work range(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[position() >= last()]"))?

Can you guys help me out?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
website = "https://langerball.de/"
driver.get(website)

for i in range(7):
    xpath_test = "//table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[position() >= last()]"
    a = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath_test)
    test_li = []
    test_li.append(a)
print(b.text for b in test_li)
```

Comment: Let me know if my solution resolved your problem

Comment: The main issue you have this code is that the xpath_test is not available on that page so nothing  will be appended to the list. The print function at the end of your code is only printing generator object of empty list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`driver.find_elements` method returns a list of web elements while you are looking for their text values. Web element text value can be received by applying the `.text` method on a web element.
So, you should iterate over the received list of web elements and extract text from  each web element in the list.
Also `test_li = []` should be defined out of the loop.
So your code could be something like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
website = "https://langerball.de/"
driver.get(website)
test_li = []
for i in range(7):
    xpath_test = "//table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[position() >= last()]"
    a_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath_test)   
    for a in a_list:
        test_li.append(a.text)
print(b.text for b in test_li)
```

P.S.
I'm not sure about the rest of your code: the `for i in range(7)` loop and the `xpath_test` XPath expression

Comment: this will still produce "<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f63f16fcb30>"

Comment: I see `//table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[position() >= last()]` doesn't match any elements. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Thanks I made small changes and it worked, it needs to be a smaller sign.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
test_li = []

xpath_test = "//table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[position() <= last()]"
a_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath_test)   
for a in a_list:
    test_li.append(a.text)
print(test_li)
```